# Defining methods on constructor

Tags: javascript, methods, constructor

Is it possible to define a method that is attached to the constructor function and not the constructors instances? For example:

```
function Person() {
 //define a method 
}
```

the method would then be accessible on the constructor itself such as:

```
Person.method() // calls the defined method
```

and the method would not be available on any instance of the Constructor:

```
var person = new Person();
person.method(); // undefined
```

Comment: `Person.method = function(){...}`

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can just define it this way:

```
function Person() {
    // constructor initialization code here
}

// define static method
Person.sayHi = function() {
    console.log("hi");
}

var bob = new Person();
Person.sayHi();    // works any time even before creating a Person object
bob.sayHi();       // undefined method
```

A function is an object that can have it's own properties (a method is just a property that happens to be a function).  Because those properties are not on the prototype, they will not be given to objects created from the Person constructor, but will be available from the Person constructor function object itself.

These are essentially what other languages call static methods as they are not associated with any instance.

Comment: You can even have property fields, e.g. `Person.message = "hi";` that gets used by Person.sayHi().

Comment: @user949300 - yep, I use non-function constructor properties for things like object id counters and things like that if you don't need privacy and they are local to a particular type of object, but not per-instance.